# Displaying an Animation on top of an ImageView

Tags: java, android, animation, random, imageview

Currently I am working on a part of my app that has an ImageView that is a building. Depending on the user's level, a random number is chosen as a hitpoint total this is taken from the health of the building.

For example, if the user has a level of 1, a random number between 0 and 10, called "hitpoints" is generated. My question is what would be the best way to display an animation of this random number over the ImageView?

I was thinking before that I could just create multiple images of the buildings all with a different number displayed on top of them but this would require me to make about 50 copies of the images and that would take up too much space.

So, is there a way to just display a small animation on top of my ImageView that I can just plug this random value into?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could put the ImageView and a TextView in a FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/building"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/your_building_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

As for the animation, you haven't specified what sort of animation you'd like (fade in, slide up/down/left/right, etc), but all you'd need to do is something like below whenever you wanted to animate the TextView containing the number:

Create a method in your Activity for the animation (the example is a fade in animation):

```
private Animation fadeInAnimation() {
    Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0f, 1.0f);
    animation.setDuration(1000); // in milliseconds
    animation.setFillEnabled(true);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    return animation;
}
```

...

```
TextView number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
```

Animate your TextView by calling the above method:

```
number.setText(yourRandomNumber.toString());
number.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation());
```